# Will unused B1/B2 visa affect future visa applications?

Tags: visas, usa

I was going to the USA for a medical observership program; my university was covering all my fees. I got a B1/B2 visa, good for 3 months, which included the details of where I was going and when. Because of some problems, I couldn't go, and didn't use the visa. Will that fact complicate my ability to get a tourism visa in the future?

Answer (score 20):

There is no reason why an unused visa should cause problems. If anything, it's the other way around - an unused visa shows that you're **not** desperate to come into the USA (if you wanted to stay illegally, you would most likely use the first chance you got). Be prepared, however, to answer questions about your unused visa during any future visa interviews (or even at the border) - you should have a better answer than "*there were some problems*".

Comment: I have had 2 unused visas valid for 5 years each but I have never been asked why I did not use them.

Comment: I've heard of a case where someone was questioned at length about an unused Canadian visa (but ultimately it didn't affect the decision, person got a new visa), I'm guessing same might happen with the US, but obviously it depends on the immigration officer.